# ASP.NET > Urlrewriting.net is working (but changes encoding) while using Request.QueryString AND IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, httprequest, url-encoding

In my webpage i use the UrlRewriting found [here](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html)

Everything worked like a charm, until the upgrade from IIS6 to IIS7.5

The Url rewriting stopped working.

After adding these lines in the web.config the UrlRewriting started once again to work.

```
<modules>
  <remove name="ScriptModule" />
  <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</modules>
```

Now the problem is that the `Request.Querystring` that i use, in my webpage gets the data with wrong encoding.

So, while using the same Request.QuesryString instead of `Αγγλίας` i get `Î±Î³î³î»Î¹î±`

Is there anything at your mind?

**UPDATE:** While make a search on [Google about this one](http://www.google.gr/search?q=%C3%8E%C2%B1%C3%8E%C2%B3%C3%AE%C2%B3%C3%AE%C2%BB%C3%8E%C2%B9%C3%AE%C2%B1) i found that Greek webpages are returned.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** I solved the problem by using RawUrl, but just in case... Is it a "kind of bug"?

Comment: what about in URL rewriter in english with IIS 7?

Comment: With IIS7 and up, UrlRewriting is part of IIS and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a bug. I would recommend using [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead.